# Dynamic String get dynamic image name in java

Tags: java

i have a dynamic String like

```
age/data/images/four_seasons1.jpg
```

from above string i need to get the image name alone (i.e.) four_seasons1.jpg

the path and the image will be a dynamic one(any image format will occure)

Please let me know how to do this in java?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for regex but if you find the pattern is fixed, A very crude solution can be a straight forward approach

```
    String url = "age/data/images/four_seasons1.jpg";

    String imageName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf( "/" )+1, url.length()) ;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the File Object.

```
new File("/path/to/file").getName()
```

You could also use String.split().

```
"/path/to/file/sdf.png".split("/")
```

This will give you an array in which you pick the last element. But the File Object is better suited.

Comment: Assuming that it's not a reference from say, a `<href>` tag...(without evidence to the contrary, this is not wrong ;))

Comment: Of course :-) But too many people work on paths on a String-basis which destroys the platform independence of Java programs. "/" vs. "\"...

Comment: I agree, I think the concept of using `File` is an excellent one, it's simple and clean. Personally, I'd use `File.separator` where possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
String text = "age/data/images/four_seasons1.jpg";

String name = text.substring(text.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
String path = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf("/"));
System.out.println(name);
System.out.println(path);
```

Outputs

```
four_seasons1.jpg
age/data/images
```

Take some time and become familiar with the [java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) API.  You'll be doing this kind of stuff a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can parse this path. As a delimiter you must take `'/'` symbol. After that you can take last parsed element.

```
String phrase = "age/data/images/four_seasons1.jpg";
String delims = "/";
String[] tokens = phrase.split(delims);
```

About String.split you can read more [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "age/data/images/four_seasons1.jpg";

String fileName = new String();

String[] arr = s.split("/");

fileName = arr[arr.length-1];

}
```

Comment: Do you really need this for loop?

Comment: @besworland as said by OP the path is dynamic... so will someone guess at which index of the arr the file name is present....

Comment: No need of loop. You can just extract the last string.

Comment: @besworland and Shashwat you ppl were right...thats why its not advisable to do stackoverflow from office.............. thanks..i will edit it at once..